# Suppose $f_n\rightarrow f$ Point wise a.e.

Tags: measure-theory, hilbert-spaces

Suppose $f_n\rightarrow f$  pointwise a.e. Show that $f_n\rightarrow f$ in $L^1$ if and only if $\lvert\lvert f_n\lvert\lvert_1 \rightarrow \lvert \lvert f\lvert\lvert_1$.

What happens if it’s all in $L^2$?

So we prove two direction, first we have $\lvert f_n-f\lvert\rightarrow 0 $ because of the pointwise convergence, then by triangle inequality, we have:
$\lvert\lvert f_n\lvert\lvert_1 - \lvert \lvert f\lvert\lvert_1\leq \lvert\lvert f_n-f\lvert\lvert_1=\int\lvert f_n-f\lvert\rightarrow0$.

But I have trouble proving the other direction? Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: This is true for all $p\in [1,\infty)$. See here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2788412/lp-norms-convergence-implies-lp-convergence/2788439#2788439

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A useful tool for this is the generalised Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem, which
allows the dominating function to be dependent on $n$.

Suppose $\|f_n\|_1 \to \|f\|_1$.

Let $g_n(x) = |f_n(x)| + |f(x)|$, $g=2|f|$, then $g_n(x) \to g(x)$ for ae. $x$, 
$\|g_n\|_1 = \|f_n\|_1+\|f\|_1$, $\|g\|_1 = 2\|f\|_1$ and $\|g_n\|_1 \to \|g\|_1$.

We have $|f_n(x)-f(x)| \le g_n(x)$ and since $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ for ae. $x$ we see that
$\|f_n-f\|_1\to 0$.

This generalises in a straightforward manner if we note that
$|a+b|^p \le 2^{p-1}(|a|^p+|b|^p)$.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Why do we need to show gn converges to g?

Comment: That is part of the generalised Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem, in the usual version the $g$ are fixed.

Comment: I see. Thank you!